# GCP GCE Agent Deletes Users and changes keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I noticed that when my VM boots, it will randomly choose between two guest environments. In the logs, I see "GCE Agent Started" with either (version 20210908.1) or (version 20200610.00). The host key changes along with the agent version. The issue is that I am only able to access my conda environments and other information on one of these versions. Is there any way I can control or choose which agent version is used on startup? Is there a way to disable or uninstall these agents?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you solve this?